# How can I know if my Asus Nexus 7 is 1st or 2nd gen?

Tags: google, nexus-7

I was given an Asus Nexus 7. How can I tell if it is the 1st or the 2nd gen?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The easiest way to tell is by checking the front and rear camera.

The first gen has front camera only and there is no rear camera. The second generation has both front and rear camera.